# Image Copy Repeat & Combine Function Size issue

Tags: c#, .net, forms, image, bitmap

```
 private void BtnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = @"D:\",
            Title = "Browse Design Files",
            CheckFileExists = true,
            CheckPathExists = true,
            DefaultExt = "tif",
            Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.TIF)|*.BMP;*.TIF|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*",
            FilterIndex = 1,
            RestoreDirectory = true,
            Multiselect = false,
            ReadOnlyChecked = true,
            ShowReadOnly = true
        };
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
               // Image OriginalImage = Image.FromFile(file);
              //  int OriginalImageDpi = (int)OriginalImage.HorizontalResolution;
                using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(file))
                {
                    int OrgImgWidth = image.Width;
                    var Xdpi = image.Density;
                    image.Format = MagickFormat.Tiff;

                    EnteredRepeat = short.Parse(TxbLenRpt.Text); // Need to ENter the no of repeats to create
                    for (int i = 0; i < EnteredRepeat; i++)
                    {
                        // image.Density = new Density(360, 360);
                        image.Write("D:\\IMAGICK\\Apped Folder\\Outfile" + i + ".tiff");
                    }
                    using (MagickImageCollection ImageColln = new MagickImageCollection())
                    {
                        string[] Filename = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\\IMAGICK\\Apped Folder\\");
                        var FilenameCount = Filename.Count();
                        foreach (var Imgfile in Filename)
                        {
                            string Path = Convert.ToString(Imgfile);
                            ImageColln.Add(Path);
                        }
                        // MontageMode mode = MontageMode.Concatenate;
                        var montageSettings = new MontageSettings()
                        {
                            TileGeometry = new MagickGeometry(FilenameCount, 0), // Specify weather in X or in Y merging
                            Shadow = false, // -shadow
                            Geometry = new MagickGeometry(-1, 0, 0, 0),
                            BorderWidth = 0,
                        };
                        using (IMagickImage result = ImageColln.Montage(montageSettings))
                        {
                            result.Density = new Density(360, 360);
                            //result.Depth = (int)ColorDepth.Depth8Bit;
                            //result.
                            result.Write("D:\\IMAGICK\\MultiRepeat.tiff");
                            result.Dispose();
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            Image DisImage = Image.FromFile("D:\\IMAGICK\\MultiRepeat.tiff");
            //pictureBox1.Image = DisImage;
            LblHeight.Text = Convert.ToString(DisImage.Height) + "Height";
            LblWidth.Text = Convert.ToString(DisImage.Width) + "width";
            LblDpi.Text = Convert.ToString(DisImage.HorizontalResolution) + "DPI";
        }
    }
```

> I am succeeded to Copy & append the Source image file multiple times & murge it to one file. My problem is Destination file size is toooo Big which creates Overload memory in computer having 16GB ram windows10 64bit. All project is developped for 64bit target system.
> After study i found that while creating target file in result, LZW compression is not given I tried lot of way but LZW compression is not applying.
> I am using MagickImage class

Updated on 17 06 2021 After @Nyerguds Suggestion but still no effect on problem

Comment: You have a serious memory leak in this code. The `Image OriginalImage = Image.FromFile(file);` part should be in a `using` block, otherwise the originally loaded files are never unlocked and never unloaded from memory.

Comment: @Nyerguds Thanks for reply. i checked removing that part also but it takes almost 120sec for desired file size. FIle Size will be ( 18144 X 46800) pixel with 720DPI resolution..... still working hard on the same but not getting succeeded.

Comment: Well, you might just be hitting ImageMagick's limits...